# How to include script inside javascript code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to implement the following code to improve my site performance and try to fire the script after scroll and wait 1 second.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.addEventListener('scroll',() =>
        setTimeout(() => {

       //Delay calendly
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://assets.calendly.com/assets/external/widget.js"></script>

        }, 1000);                                           
  );

</script>
```

I have this calendly script that I want to delay. The thing is I can't include the script inside another script, so, are there any way to make it?

Thanks!

Comment: No, there's no way to add a script tag inside a script tag. You can create a new script element and place it somewhere in the DOM tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with only the vanilla dom:

```js
// ... something happens
var scr_elem = document.createElement('script');
scr_elem.type = 'text/javascript'
scr_elem.src = 'https://assets.calendly.com/assets/external/widget.js'
document.body.appendChild(scr_elem);
```

Comment: Thanks Gavin, it just work perfecly! I will take for future projects, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a script `dynamically` and append to the `head/body`.

```
let timer;
window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  if (!timer) {
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      const script = document.createElement("script");
      script.type = "text/javascript";
      script.src = "https://assets.calendly.com/assets/external/widget.js";
      document.body.appendChild(script);
    }, 1000);
  }
});
```